# Web scraping - SAPPLY function - Error in readBin(5L, "raw", 65536L) : Failure when receiving data from the peer

Tags: r, web-scraping, sapply

I am struggling with web scraping. Chunk A works fine but Chunk B doesn't, somehow.
If you could possibly run code A and B on your computer and give me a hint, what's wrong with B?

The best solution would be, if someone knows a code that takes all the hyperlinks with the same name (here 'Statement'). Therefore, I would not need so many different for-loops.

Lots of kisses to everyone who is already puzzling!

Ciocclata

What I tried so far: tried to separately scrape the code from the web pages. I checked the html source code.

**CHUNK A (works)**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

statements = data.table(NULL)

#2005,2004,2002: (YES)

for (pages_years in c(2005,2004,2002)){
   link = paste0("https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomchistorical", pages_years , ".htm")
   page = read_html(link)

   statement_links = page %>% html_nodes(".col-md-6+ .col-md-6 p:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.federalreserve.gov", ., sep="")

   get_statement = function(statement_link){
   statement_page = read_html(statement_link)
   statement = statement_page %>% html_nodes("td p") %>% html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
   return(statement)
 }
   statement = sapply(statement_links, FUN = get_statement, USE.NAMES = F)


   get_date = function(date_link){
   date_page = read_html(date_link)
   date = date_page %>% html_nodes("i") %>% html_text()
   return(date)
 }
   date = sapply(statement_links, FUN = get_date, USE.NAMES = F)
   date = format(mdy(date), "%Y-%m-%d")

   print(paste("Page:", pages_years))

   statements = rbind(statements, data.table(date, statement, stringsAsFactors = F))
}


DT = statements
DT = DT[date<=2021]
DT = DT[order(date)]

View(DT)
```

**CHUNK B (doesn't work)**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

 
statements = data.table(NULL)


#2010,2008,2007:

for (pages_years in c(2010,2008,2007)){
    link = paste0("https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomchistorical", pages_years , ".htm")
    page = read_html(link)

    statement_links = page %>% html_nodes(".col-md-12 p:nth-child(1) a , .col-md-6+ .col-md-6 p:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.federalreserve.gov", ., sep="")

 
    get_statement = function(statement_link){
    statement_page = read_html(statement_link)
    statement = statement_page %>% html_nodes(".hidden-sm+ .col-md-8") %>% html_text()
    return(statement)
  }
    statement = sapply(statement_links, FUN = get_statement, USE.NAMES = F)
    get_date = function(date_link){
    date_page = read_html(date_link)
    date = date_page %>% html_nodes(".article__time") %>% html_text()
    return(date)
  }
    date = sapply(statement_links, FUN = get_date, USE.NAMES = F)
    date = format(mdy(date), "%Y-%m-%d")
    print(paste("Page:", pages_years))
    statements = rbind(statements, data.frame(date, statement, stringsAsFactors = F))
}

DT = statements
DT = DT[date<=2021]
DT = DT[order(date)]

View(DT)
```

Comment: Avoid growing objects in loop. Build a list of data.tables then `rbindlist` *once* outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to have a `tryCatch` option.  With `possibly/safely` from `purrr`, this can be done more easily

```
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
get_statement <- possibly(function(statement_link){
    statement_page = read_html(statement_link)
    statement = statement_page %>% html_nodes(".hidden-sm+ .col-md-8") %>% html_text()
    return(statement)
  }, otherwise = NA)
  
  
get_date  <- possibly(function(date_link){
    date_page = read_html(date_link)
    date = date_page %>% html_nodes(".article__time") %>% html_text()
    return(date)
  }, otherwise = NA)

for (pages_years in c(2010,2008,2007)){
    link = paste0("https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/fomchistorical", pages_years , ".htm")
    page = read_html(link)

    statement_links = page %>% html_nodes(".col-md-12 p:nth-child(1) a , .col-md-6+ .col-md-6 p:nth-child(2) a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.federalreserve.gov", ., sep="")

 
  
    statement = sapply(statement_links, FUN = get_statement, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
   
    date = sapply(statement_links, FUN = get_date, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
    date = format(mdy(date), "%Y-%m-%d")
    print(paste("Page:", pages_years))
    statements = rbind(statements, data.frame(date, statement, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}
#[1] "Page: 2010"
#[1] "Page: 2008"
#[1] "Page: 2007"

DT = statements
DT = DT[date<=2021]
DT = DT[order(date)]
```

-output

```
> dim(DT)
[1] 30  2
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Unfortunately, the command `View(DT)` results in an empty table. To make the code run, I added: 
`library(lubridate)` # for the date
`library(data.table)`
`statements = data.table(NULL)` How did you manage to get `[1] 30 2` ?

Comment: @Ciocclata I was using the same code and there was nothing else I did